# Minimal Subset Sum Superset

Tags: co.combinatorics

For a positive integer set $m \in \mathbb{N}_{+}^k$, we define the set of subset sums
$$
M = \left\{ \sum_{i \in I} m_i \mid I \subseteq \{1,\dots,k\} \right\}.
$$

Given a finite set of positive integers $C \subset \mathbb{N}_+$, what is the minimal $k$ and the corresponding $m$ such that 
$$
M \supseteq C \textrm{ ? } 
$$
Let's define $n = \max(C)$. It is easy to see that $k \leq \log_2 ( n +1)$ as $M = \{1,\dots,n\}$ for $m = [1, 2, 4, 8, \dots, 2^{k-1}]$. Also, a solution can be recovered by iterative elimination of $C$. For example: 
$$\begin{eqnarray}\require{cancel} C = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14] \\
[1, 2, \cancel{3}, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14] \\
[1, 2, 5, \cancel{7}, \cancel{8}, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14] \\
[1, 2, 5, 9, \cancel{10}, \cancel{12}, 13, 14] \\
[1, 2, 5, 9, 13, \cancel{14}],
\end{eqnarray}$$ 
which is viable, but non-optimal compared to $m = [1, 2, 5, 7]$. Is this a known problem and is there an efficient method to find minimal $m$?

Comment: Are you requiring that the generating set m be a proper subset of C? If not, the log (of the largest element of C) bound should work similarly for C.  Gerhard "Or Is That Too Easy?" Paseman, 2018.04.30.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman All set relations are not necessarily proper. I clarified this above. The bound works but, it is by no means tight, right?

Comment: I am not an expert here.  I think the bound is asymptotically tight.  Guy's Unsolved Problems In Number Theory should be a good launching point to research this problem.  I can't recall any good search terms right now . Gerhard "Ask Me After Some Coffee" Paseman, 2018.04.30.